# conda command not found even though path is exported

Tags: macos, anaconda

I installed anaconda3 into my home directory.  This is what I am seeing within the terminal:

[image]

and my .bash_profile looks like this:

export PATH="/Users/spotter/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

So I don't understand why conda is not being recognized.  When I navigate to anaconda3/bin there is a file called `conda` in there, but even when I try to call it within that pathway it is still not found.

Comment: Also, as I posted on (what I presume is) your other question, please don't post terminal output in images. Thank you!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Spotter, your path to conda is incorrect.

I'm on High Sierra MAC OS and just installed Anaconda3 via HomeBrew command. I had issue with running :

```
 conda
```

It'd also give me:

```
-bash: conda: command not found
```

I tried running:

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

but it needs ENTIRE path.  so here are the correct steps:

```
$ nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Now export the ENTIRE path, in my case it was:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

Exit out and run:

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

Then try:

```
$ conda
```

it'll output:

```
 $ conda --version
    conda 4.4.10
```

Answer (score 3):

I had to type `source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate`.

Comment: This is not the recommended best practice any more (after conda 4.4).

Answer (score 3):

For anyone that landed here that is using a non-standard shell (zsh for example) the installer 5.3.1 currently changes the bash_profile not the current active default terminal.

Just open ~/.bash_profile, find the block that is added by the installer and copy it into your .zshrc file (if using zsh)

Answer (score 2):

in Mac OS, for conda >4,4, the conventional way of exporting path (`export PATH="Users/myuser/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"`) is NOT recommended anymore. First, see what is error message in your terminal in Mac when you type `conda --version`. If it says `zsh conda not found` then you are using ZSH terminal, so modifying any bash file is useless. In this case, you need to edit your `.zprofile`. on the other hand, if you get error like `bash conda not found` you edit `.bash_profile`. Lets, say we have zsh error, then type in terminal:

```
sudo nano ~./zprofile
```

located your `conda.sh` file by searching in your finder. Most probably it is in 
`~/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh`
(for me it was like:  `/Users/hasbah/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh`, but instead of anaconda3, it might be conda)

then you type in `.zhprfile` this:

```
. /Users/myuser/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate base
```

then you save (ctrl+X and Y when was asked to save) and restart the terminal.
Now if you type `conda --version` you will see it.
so, in short:

```
sudo nano ~/.zproflie
. /Users/myuser/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate base

save ./zproflie file
close terminal
open new terminal
conda --version
```

Comment: On macOS Big Sur v11.1, the path of conda is `/opt/anaconda3/bin/` instead of `/Users/myname/anaconda3/bin/`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding the `~/anaconda3/bin` to your `PATH`, you should add

```
. ~/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate base
```

to your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`, or type that in a shell, if you don't want it to be activated for each shell. This is the recommended way to activate conda since conda 4.4. See: https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#440-2017-12-20