# conda: command not found even though Anaconda is in path (WSL)

Tags: anaconda, conda

I've tried/checked related posts but I can't find what's stopping my Windows Subsystem for Linux from running conda.

These paths (I have verified that they are correct and exist) are in my PATH.

```
/mnt/c/Users/user/Anaconda3:
/mnt/c/Users/user/Anaconda3/Library/mingw-w64/bin:
/mnt/c/Users/user/Anaconda3/Library/usr/bin:
/mnt/c/Users/user/Anaconda3/Library/bin:
/mnt/c/Users/user/Anaconda3/Scripts
```

Note that I added the new lines so that it is more readable, the spaces aren't actually present in my PATH.

When I run `conda --version` on command prompt I get `conda 4.7.12`, but I get this error when I run the same thing on Linux: `conda:command not found`

Also, I tried closing and opening my terminal and shifting the paths to the front of PATH (not that it matters but I was desperate), both didn't help.

Already referred to:
[How to run Conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675907/how-to-run-conda)
[conda command not found even though path is exported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49821930/conda-command-not-found-even-though-path-is-exported)

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: You have to separately install Anaconda (I recommend [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) instead) in WSL using the Linux version. They are completely different installs and do not work across the virtualization.

Comment: I have the same issue with Miniconda.
`$ conda
-bash: conda: command not found`